# DNAT with iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I'm trying to make a DNAT on interface eth0:0 to another IP 192.168.1.12 on port 43, but it's not working, what can be wrong?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0:0 --dport 43 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:43
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 43 -j MASQUERADE
```

To listen on any interface is working:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 43 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:43
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.12 --dport 43 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

eth0:0 is an alias, not an actual interface, so iptables knews nothing about that. The first rule should be rewritten like following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 ...
```

In the second rule, it's strongly recommended to specify outgoing interface via "-o ...". You can get it using following command:

```
ip route get 192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Can I use IP instead of interface on PREROUTING?

Comment: What I need is to have 3 different DNAT to external IP 192.168.1.12 on port 43 with origin from 3 different IP on the server on eth0:0, eth0:1, eth0:3 with IP's, for example 192.168.2.1, 192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.3 (The IP's mensioned are not real IP's)